# UIButton is moving up when navigation bar hidden

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios7, uibutton

I am adding the one UIButton in bottom of view -

```
CGRect frame      = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;

UIButton *menu_btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset, frame.size.height - 55, 55, 55)];
[self.view addSubview:menu_btn];
```

And in the view i have UITableview and i am hiding the uinavigation bar when scrolling down in the list and showing when scrolling up.

menu_btn is moving up and down with the list, I want to fix this button.

Anyone please suggest me,how i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I added in navigationController.view and its working fine. Thanks guys.

```
CGRect frame      = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
UIButton *menu_btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset, frame.size.height - 55, 55, 55)];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:menu_btn];
```